# Added overflow-y scrollbar to div hides my x-overflow

Tags: css

I want to add a scrollbar to a `<div>`. On the x-axis i have an overflow which I want to be shown.

But when I add `overflow-y: auto` to the style it cuts out the x-overflow aswell.

Here is an example: [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7zygm3f0/)

Is there a way to do that?

**EDIT**

Heres the code of the situation. I have a sidebar which open/closes. And the button needs to have a -margin to be visible when the sidebar is closed. You can see it in action right here: [Website with sidebar](https://www.fabiansquinobal.com)

```
        <div class="sidebar right">

            <!-- Sidebaredge with button to toggle -->  

            <div style="width: 100px; height: 50px; margin-top: 16px; margin-left: -100px; position: relative; font-size: 10px">

            <a href="#" class="sidebaropenclose" data-side="right"><div id="openclosebutton" class="open-close-button"></div></a>

            </div>
```

And here is the code from the css-file:

```
    .sidebar.right {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 20%;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    background-color: #659DBD;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #FFFFFF;
}

.sidebars > .sidebar {
    font-family: 'Josefin Slab', serif;
    position: fixed;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: left;
}
```

I need the sidebar to be scroll-able because of different resolutions and the open-close button to be visible for the sidebar.

Comment: Can you please add your code to your question here?

Comment: Your example site won't load for me. But is the issue that the button with the negative margin won't stay visible when the sidebar is hidden?

Comment: yes, when its hidden and visible.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add both an explicit x & y overflow?

```
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: visible;
```

I believe this happens because setting the one overflow direction only still sets a new *block formatting context* Here's [more info about it](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2009/07/23/overflow-a-secret-benefit/).

Comment: I tryed that, but that doesn´t fixes my problem. The x-overflow still got cut.